# Node-Red flows not running on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, node-red

I have created a deployment of node-red. I have checked the logs and says the server is running. However when I point the browser to 127.0.0.1:1880, it does not show anything.

Deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nodered
  name: nodered
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nodered
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nodered
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nodered
        image: nodered/node-red:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 256Mi
            cpu: "0.2"
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
            cpu: "1"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1880
        volumeMounts:
        - name: nodered-claim
          mountPath: /data/nodered
          # subPath: nodered <-- not needed in your case
      volumes:
      - name: nodered-claim
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: nodered-claim
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: small-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /data
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - minikube
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nodered-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: local-storage
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
```

Pod logs:

[image]

Browser:

[image]

I was expecting node-red flows when I pointed the browser to 127.0.0.1:1880.

Comment: You probably need to include a lot more information about your kiuberneate cluster here, e.g. is it on the same machine as your browser? Does it have an Ingress Controller deployed. The instructions in the logs about 127.0.0.1 do not apply to Node-RED running in containers.

Comment: my cluster is running locally. I have deployed it as a NodePort service. I have not configured it to have an ingress controller

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a service resource. Otherwise you will not be able to access a cluster service.

Something like this will give you access to node-red at: http://IP_of_cluster:30000

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node-red-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: nodered
  ports:
    - port: 1880
      targetPort: 1880
      nodePort: 30000
```

If you want something more production-ready, you should think of using an ingress resource:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Comment: Hi, I have created a new deployment after adding the nodeport service. The pod is running but it is still saying the site can't be reached. I have tried pointing the browser to the nodeport ip:1880

Comment: You will most likely also need to deploy a Ingress Controller and then create an Ingress resource (at which point you will also need to use hostnames to do virtual host based routing)

Comment: Is there a detailed instruction on how I can do this?

Comment: You should use `http://node-ip:30000` not `:1880` the service definition maps the pod's port 1880 to node port 30000

Comment: I tried that, but still it can't reach :(

Comment: are you able to run `kubectl get pods` and get a response? Maybe something is preventing you from accessing the cluster even from localhost.

Comment: Yes I checked that, the nodered pod is running. I don't know why it isn't working. I did have nodered containers on docker before but I disabled them before running kubernetes. Could it be a reason?

Comment: Update: I deleted every containers I had and tried deploying this. Still did not work :(